# Opendaylight Dlux how to make flow table?

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow, opendaylight

I downloaded mininet, opendaylight, etc.. and I wanted to add flow table to switches.I used `dpctl` and `sh ovs-ofctl` command. but it was too hard to add flow tables to each switches.

I want to add flow table on Dlux UI. But I don't know how to fill in that blank.
I made a topology by:

`sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1,port=6633 --switch ovsk --topo tree,2,2`

I could see the Node Id of switches. it was `"openflow:1","openflow:2","openflow:3"`

So i input openflow:1.. but it occured an error!
i don't know how to fill that blank

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a flow manually through the Mininet terminal like this :

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow [SWITCH_NAME] ip,nw_dst=192.168.0.1,actions=drop
```

- *NOTE* : Try typing `sh` before the command if it does not work.

That was an example flow. See [this link](http://www.pica8.com/document/v2.3/pdf/ovs-commands-reference.pdf) for the whole ovs commands reference.

Comment: Thank you!
Then, there is no way to add flow tables on Web ?

Comment: @Jungwon what do you mean? Do you want to add flows to a table in a switch?

Comment: Yes I want that

Comment: @Jungwon you can google exactly what your flow wants to do. What exactly do you want, in case I can help?